# ActiveModelSerializer and VOID types responses

Tags: sorbet

Solved!

Kids, don't define `read_attribute_for_serialization` to return `void`

So I'm trying to integrate sorbet in one of my rails apps. I've added sorbet in the Gemfile as so

```
gem "sorbet-runtime", "~> 0.5.5657"
gem "sorbet-rails", "~> 0.6.5.1"
gem "sorbet", "~> 0.5.5657", group: [:development, :test]
```

All looks good an I was able to add sigs to `Price` class and resolve issues with type checking inside the app.

The problem I'm experiencing is the return values from serializers

So the serializer looks roughly like this

```
# typed: false
# frozen_string_literal: true

class MySuperAwesomeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :start_date

  has_one :price, serializer: PriceSerializer
end
```

In specs, when I want to validate the return value from the associated (`has_one`) attribute I get this

```
{
  start_date: 2020-05-22,
  price: {
    total_amount: T::Private::Types::Void::VOID,
    taxless_amount: T::Private::Types::Void::VOID,
    vat_amount: T::Private::Types::Void::VOID
  }
}
```

Price serializer looks roughly like this

```
# typed: false
# frozen_string_literal: true
class PriceSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :taxless_amount, :total_amount, :vat_amount
end
```

I fail to understand what and why is exactly happening here. Thanks in advance

EDIT: added the "solution" at the top of the post

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t encountered this problem before, but it looks like a potential sorbet bug.

`T::Private::Types::Void::Void` is the return type that sorbet swap out for methods that have `void` as the [return type](https://sorbet.org/docs/sigs#returns-void-annotating-return-types). In this case, you don’t define any `sig` for the `attributes` so it shouldn’t have stub out the returning value.

To work around, you can define explicit sig for those attributes like

```
sig { returns(Integer) }
def taxless_amount
...
end
```

I haven’t tried but this may also work

```
sig { returns(Integer) }
attributes :taxless_amount
```

Edit: can you show the actual PriceSerializer class btw? It looks like it works without problem for the attributes in the other Serializer.

Comment: Thanks! The weekend was the best solution - I've added the "fix" at the top of my post. I've overridden `read_attribute_for_serialization` and there I defined a sig that returned a void.

Answer (score 0):

If you define `read_attribute_for_serialization` don't do it this way:

```
  sig { params(attr: Symbol).void }
  def read_attribute_for_serialization(attr)
    public_send(attr)
  end
```